# Entityframework Concurrency

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, concurrency

I have the following Scenario:
I have 2 web api functions, which delete / insert data into a SQL Server database. The data Access is handled via .net entityframework v6. The insert / delete methods were only called from a local running c# program. I am using HttpClient class to call the web api methods. The web methods works as follows, when I call insert all existing records will be deleted and the new ones will be inserted, so there is no real update process.

Here are my 2 functions:

```
[HttpDelete()]
public async Task<int> DeleteStartlist(int eventid, int run, int heat, string category)
{
    _data.dbsStartlistEntries.RemoveRange(_data.dbsStartlistEntries.Where(s => s.Event.Id == eventid && s.RoundOrder == run && s.HeatOrder == heat && s.Category == category));
    return await _data.SaveChangesAsync();
}

[HttpPost()]
public async Task<int> UpdateStartlists(int eventid, List<StartlistEntry> en)
{
    try
    {
        if (en.Count == 0)
            return 0;

        var xdel = await DeleteStartlist(eventid, en[0].RoundOrder, en[0].HeatOrder, en[0].Category);
        var ev = await _data.dbsEvents.FindAsync(eventid);
        if (ev != null)
        {
            en.ForEach(e => e.Event = ev);
            _data.dbsStartlistEntries.AddRange(en);
        }
        return await _data.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

But now I have the following Problem. For example when I call the Update Method 10 times in a row without waiting between the function calls I receive following exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

For me this sounds like a concurrency Problem, but I do not really know how to solve it. 
So here is my question, is there a way to let the api calls wait for each other server side, or are they always running concurrent or is there a way to lock the database?

Comment: Where is `_data` defined?  Are you perhaps using the same data context across multiple requests?  As for making them wait for each other, how are they being called?  Normally the consuming code would manage the synchronization of the operations.

Comment: _data is defined in the API Class, do you think i should define it in the methods?

Comment: You could, sure.  (I would unless I had explicit reason not to.)  Let me clarify... *How* is it defined?  For example, if it's `static` or in some other way shared across requests then you'd run into all sorts of concurrency problems.  You definitely want to make sure any given atomic request to this web service encapsulates its own isolated data context.  Though it's entirely possible that this has nothing to do with the error.  Just a guess.

Comment: If this really is a concurrency problem (such as one request issuing a `DELETE` for a record it knows about after another concurrent request already deleted that record) then you'd probably start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application  It's really a matter of defining how the logic should handle concurrency, generally falling into one of a handful of known concurrency models.

Comment: _data is not static, i have a class called API and data is a private not static member of the class.